# Connected Set $z^2+\bar z^2 = 3$?

Tags: complex-analysis

A question in complex analysis that I have across but didn't know how to tackle. Is the set where $z$ is complex number such that $z^2+\bar z^2 = 3$ connected?

Answer (score 4):

Write $z=x+iy$; then
$$
z^2+\bar{z}^2=2(x^2-y^2)
$$
so your set is the same as the curve
$$
x^2-y^2=\frac{3}{2}
$$
which is a hyperbola.

> Now consider the sets $H^+=\{(x,y):x>0\}$ and $H^{-}=\{(x,y):x<0\}$; then your set $S$ can be written $S=(H^+\cap S)\cup(H^-\cap S)$, that is, as the union of two non empty and disjoint (relatively) open sets.

Comment: In particular, the set has two components, one where $x \ge \sqrt{3/2}$ and one where $x \le - \sqrt{3/2}$.

Comment: @ToddLeason You spoiled the surprise! `;-)`

Comment: Sorry for that!